# Variable cannot access outside .then()

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to set a authenticator for my local application. Found that I am not able to access my var outside my .then() method

```
var authenticated = false;
Auth.findtheUser({
}).then(user => {
  verified= user.name.verified;
  console.log("authenticated11", verified)
}
).catch(err => console.log(err));
console.log("authenticated", verified)
```

the output for authenticated11 output comes as true but not the one at the end
Could anyone help me out on this. New to javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You cant use the result of an asynchronous function directly after it in JS.  See this question: [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: The question does have lot of information in it i am not sure promise would work for my case

Comment: You are using a promise in your current code.  Then .then() function is called after findtheUser resolves.

Answer (score 0):

According to what you described in a comment in this answer. You are facing an exception related to the scope.

```js
var authenticated = false;
Auth.findtheUser({
  }).then(user => {
    verified= user.name.verified;
    console.log("authenticated11", verified)
}
).catch(err => console.log(err));
// This will throw an exception because verified does not exist in this scope
console.log("authenticated", verified)
```

You should change that to this

```js
var authenticated = false;
var verified;
Auth.findtheUser({
  }).then(user => {
    verified= user.name.verified;
    console.log("authenticated11", verified)
}
).catch(err => console.log(err));
// This will throw an exception because verified does not exist in this scope
console.log("authenticated", verified)
```

Comment: When i declare in this way 
The compiler days verified is not defined no-undef

Comment: Ok that is different! You got that exception because you had not declared the variable before and the console log is out of the scope of "verified" variable. I'll edit my answer to you

Comment: I tried this approach before asking the question in stackoverflow. The answer you posted did not work, the output for the verified var is undefined

Comment: You can't log it out of the scope of the promise

Comment: That is what my issue is 
I want the variable to be used outside of the promise block